# Share control between multiple Wpf controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

I have 3 WPF controls, Parent1 Parent2 and Child. Only one Parent control is used at a time.
Parent1 and Parent2 both use Child control. Currently I am spinning up Parent1 and Parent2 controls in the beginning and hiding one control as required.
Now I want to add the ability to change/save some child settings. Is there a way I could pass the Child control between the Parents so that state is saved in both?

Comment: That's an overcomplicated way to do it. Instead, write a class representing the state of the "child control". Give each parent viewmodel a reference to the same shared instance of that class. Then write a DataTemplate for that class, and give each parent control a ContentControl using that DataTemplate for its ContentTemplate. Each parent's view would bind its reference to the child class to its own content control.

Comment: But if you have no viewmodels and you don't want to use MVVM, just reparent it. Make sure you put all that code in event handlers.

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me how to reparent in this case? UserControl.AddChild / RemoveChild / Childern are not valid.

Comment: What do you mean by "not valid"? Won't compile, throws an exception? I've written code that moved children from a Grid to an ItemsControl subclass: `grid.Children.Remove(child); myItemControlSubclass.Items.Add(child);` You're nuts doing it this way, but that's not my problem.